# Using Powershell to automating a bat file that ends with PAUSE

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0

I have a batch file that I can't change, but I want to automate with Powershell 2.0.  It ends with a `PAUSE` command, which displays:

`Press any key to continue...`

Is there an way to call this batch file from a powershell script, but have it exit without needing a user to press something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can pipe anything into the `cmd` process:

```
'' | cmd /c foo.cmd
```

which will be treated as input by `cmd` and that's enough for `pause` to stop pausing.

Sample code [here](http://svn.lando.us/joey/Public/SO/3430112).